# How to identify a number from a sequence of numbers and letters?? (c#)

Tags: c#, c#-5.0

I have a sequence of numbers and letters that is generated randomly and those are some e.g. of it:

```
5e1Y9p0f5N05zJBDhtg8u2W3Z57YGCBD7W0BNi78glc1u5d78q36A49cJ316AUg2a8QF9xFwL746zjVTh0xZb122iBDTBVs29FDX714YDn6DI81iwibOor4AP8u5Fisbr2D4Hruzg4dDlm2aul3MVP3s7QK61A72Uaniu9w4d4AGG0m5
```

and I want to do some calculations on the numbers only
note that if there is more than one number behind each other then I want them as a whole number

how can I identify the numbers??

Comment: SO is not a code writing service. Try something, if you get stuck post the code you have and say what you are stuck on

Answer (score 1):

I think using regex would be the easiest way to accomplish this.

```
string strValue = "5e1Y9p0f5N05zJBDhtg8u2W3Z57YGCBD7W0BNi78glc1u5d78q36A4 9cJ316AUg2a8QF9xFwL746zjVTh0xZb122 iBDTBVs29FDX714YDn6DI81iwibOor4AP8u5Fisbr2D4Hruzg4dDlm2aul3MVP3s7QK61A72Uaniu9w4d4AGG0m5";
Regex reg = new Regex("[0-9]+");
List<string> matches = reg.Matches(strValue).Select(matchItem => matchItem.Value).ToList();
```

This would return a list of string. You would need to parse them and iterate.

Note this uses linq.

Answer (score -1):

```
    string strValue = "5e1Y9p0f5N05zJBDhtg8u2W3Z57YGCBD7W0BNi78glc1u5d78q36A4 9cJ316AUg2a8QF9xFwL746zjVTh0xZb122 iBDTBVs29FDX714YDn6DI81iwibOor4AP8u5Fisbr2D4Hruzg4dDlm2aul3MVP3s7QK61A72Uaniu9w4d4AGG0m5";
    Regex reg = new Regex("[0-9]+");
    List<int> matches = reg.Matches(strValue).Select(matchItem => int.Parse(matchItem.Value)).ToList();
    
    foreach(var item in matches)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
```